# Android listview item color change

Tags: android

I have the following list adapter that uses an inflater, I've tried adding the color change here but it changes every item not just the one clicked.

```
private class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<jsonData>{

    private List<jsonData> jList;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<jsonData> jList) {
        super(context, resource, jList);
        this.jList = jList;
    }
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;

                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listviewact_layout, null);
                            v.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.list_selector);
                }

                jsonData jd = jList.get(position);

                if (jd != null) {             
                    TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.memberName);
                    TextView dateJoined = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dateJoined);
                    if (name != null) {
                        name.setText("Member Name: " + jd.name);
                    }
                    if (dateJoined != null) {
                        dateJoined.setText("Joined: " + getNewDate(jd.joined));
                    }
                }

                return v;
            }
```

I am able to get the item position also, most of it works fine except the colors.  I also tried adding a resource file for the selector, but I get the same result.

UPDATE: This seems to work.  I have a glitch though when I scroll the item colors go crazy.

```
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {          

            if(selectedItemPosition != position){
                //Resets old item to original color
                parent.getChildAt(selectedItemPosition).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);                    
                selectedItemPosition = position;
            }               
        }
```

Comment: Write the color changing code in onclickListner

Comment: Why not set the background drawable in the layout resource itself? Also, you are using another layout resource as a background drawable?

Comment: That was just an example I had used that didn't work.  I added the color change to the OnItemClickListener and it works, except the color doesn't reset.  I'll have to look into that some more but I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `android:listSelector` not `android:background` for adding selector xml file to ur listview

```
         <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector">
        </ListView>
```

Try this selector xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_enabled="true" 
 android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/android:blue" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
 android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/android:transparent" />
<item
 android:drawable="@color/android:black" />
```

Comment: I'll try this method also.

Comment: I have this in the list selector.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/black" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" />
</selector>

Comment: make state_pressed TRUE like this: <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/black" />

Comment: Neither of these seems to work, I tried it several ways, it seems to highlight every item not just one.  I want the selected item to be blue.

Comment: I had to add the  v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector); back in and it works, it fixed the scrolling issue also.  Now I just have to get it to stay selected.  I assume change transparent to blue.

Comment: I got a decent result using this answer, however keeping the selected item a certain color is more difficult it would seem.  My first method does that but gets messed up when I scroll.

Answer (score 0):

```
view.setbackground();

Changes the background of entire list .since your view points to that list not a field in that list.
try this

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- focused and pressed-->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: Same result, and doesn't keep the item selected.  I tried setting it as a BackgroundResource in the onItemClick view also, it worked "differently" but not correct yet. Even using the onItemClick view it makes the whole list blue.